# Could we add a delay between bounties instead of doubling the bounty amount?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Last week, I offered a 250 rep bounty on a question I thought was interesting and for which I wanted an authoritative reference. Two users posted considerably complete answers and I wanted to reward both of them. I gave the bounty to one of them today and tried to offer a second bounty, but I realized the bounty cost had doubled to 500. I wouldn't typically care, but I don't think either answer deserves more than the other. I'd like to reward them equally.

The bounty cost is explained in the [What is a bounty?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) help page and I had not read it before.

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the
>   minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on
>   the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and
>   so on).

I understand there's a possibility for abuse if the bounty process isn't controlled. A user could simply give all their reputation to someone else.

However, I would prefer having to wait 24-48 hours before I could offer another bounty to having to offer a bounty amount I don't consider reasonable (I would maybe feel differently with smaller rep amounts).

What's the rationale behind doubling the amount versus enforcing a delay when offering multiple bounties?

Comment: I remember one of the reasons for the increase was that someone was using 50-rep bounties to endlessly to advertise their product.

Comment: @Mysticial Shouldn't that be flagged/deleted as spam, then?

Comment: @AlexisKing You can judge for yourself here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91814/repeated-use-of-bounties-for-promotional-purposes I wouldn't go so far to say that it's spam.

Comment: @Mysticial Closing/locking that question seems sufficient.